PyQt5 QSilder: Change handle on hover groove
I want to design my Video Player like the one on Youtube. The slider is a thin line and when the mouse hovers the slider its handle change to a cycle.
To get this work I created a class, inherited from QSlider and declared mouse entered/left events. Then on the events I reset the whole QSS of the slider for the hover state and normal state.
It works, but I don't like it. I want to do it more fancy. Is there a way in QSS to change the handle in the groove block or any other way than resetting the whole QSS?
class VideoPlayer(QWidget):

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super(VideoPlayer, self).__init__()

        self.positionSliderQSS = """
            QSlider {            
                background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
            }
            
            QSlider::groove:horizontal {
                height: 3px;
                background: #C6C6C6;
                margin: 2px 0;
            }
            
            QSlider::groove:horizontal:hover {
                height: 3px;
                background: #C6C6C6;
                margin: 2px 0;
            }

            QSlider::handle:horizontal {
                background: red;
                margin: 2px 0;
                width: 1px;
                height: 3px;
            }
            
            QSlider::handle:horizontal:hover {
                background: red;
                border: 1px solid #FF0000;
                width: 10px;
                height: 10px;
                margin: -5px -1px;
                border-radius: 5px;
            }
                
            QSlider::add-page:horizontal {
                height: 3px;
                background: #C6C6C6;
                margin: 2px 0;
            }
            
            QSlider::sub-page:horizontal {
                background: #FF0000;
                height: 3px;
                margin: 2px 0;
            }
            """

        self.positionSliderQSSHover = """
            QSlider {            
                background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
            }
            
            QSlider::groove:horizontal {
                height: 5px;
                background: #C6C6C6;
                margin: 2px 0;
            }

            QSlider::handle:horizontal {
                background: red;
                border: 1px solid #FF0000;
                width: 10px;
                height: 10px;
                margin: -5px -1px;
                border-radius: 5px;
            }
            QSlider::add-page:horizontal {
                height: 5px;
                background: #C6C6C6;
                margin: 2px 0;
            }
            
            QSlider::sub-page:horizontal {
                background: #FF0000;
                height: 5px;
                margin: 2px 0;
            }
            """

        self._positionSlider = Slider(Qt.Horizontal)
        self._positionSlider.onMouseEntered.connect(self._onPositionSliderEntered)
        self._positionSlider.onMouseLeft.connect(self._onPositionSliderLeft)

    def _onPositionSliderEntered(self, event) -> None:
        self._positionSlider.setStyleSheet(self.positionSliderQSSHover)

    def _onPositionSliderLeft(self, event) -> None:
        self._positionSlider.setStyleSheet(self.positionSliderQSS)


What do you mean by "more fancy"? You could provide two images, one with what you currently have, and the other with what you want (do a mock up with an image editor, or take a screenshot from a slider similar to your needs).

I mean, how to code this more fancy. What I have is like the player on youtube, it's already what I want to have . But I don't like the way I coded it. I don't like that I change the whole QSS to achieve the hover effect.

If it works, then that's it. We don't provide reviews or suggestions about code or implementations. QSlider is a complex widget that draws all of its contents on its own, and applying new style sheets always requires a recomputation of all existing (and inherited) ones. Shortly put: setStyleSheet() always resets the style, and there's no way to do something like "keep the existing style, change only rule XYZ". The only alternative would be to manually draw contents by overriding paintEvent(), considering widget geometries and using QStyle functions. For what you want, it's not worth it.
